# AChartEngine crash on release

Tags: crash, release, achartengine

Great library, works well in debug.

However, after I exported a signed application package, it crashes every time I try to fire up a chart. Just, puff!!!

I'm using sdk 19 and targeting 16 min.

Does AChartEngine have any special ProGuard settings?

Any suggestions?

Here is part of the logcat (thanks to keshav):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:739)
at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:91)
at a.a.b.onDraw(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13944)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12838)
```

Comment: You should post log trace if any .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How does one go at doing that with a signed application? I'm thick, please bear with me.

Comment: Run your app and see the logcat, you can not select the app but looking at whole trace you can easily see errors.

Comment: Hold on. Are you saying that if I export a signed application package, I can still run it from eclipse on the emulator? How?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special just attach device to system and run your app, when crash will happen logcat will so error message.